# Как впихнуть два метода в одну функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

У меня есть бот на aiogram. Задача бота принимать в себя данные от пользователей. Я не хочу убирать концепцию callback'a в боте но... инлайн сообщения требуют аргумента в функции

```py
async def checkname(query: CallbackQuery):
```

Но так как бот принимает на себя вводимые данные, то он должен читать текст сообщений пользователей. Но тут необходим:

```py
async def checkname(message: types.Message):
     msg = message.text
```

Но так как аио не принимает в себя два аргумента функций одновременно, я задался вопросом - каким образом можно запихнуть в одну функцию И callback И message

Comment: Так погоди-ка, что ты вообще хочешь сделать? Колбек это когда юзер клацает на инлайн кнопку, месседж_хендлер это когда юзер отправляет данные боту (текст, фото и ТД). Как ты вообще хочешь и объединить. Для чего конкретно это вам, опишите свою задачу и я уверен вам не придется извращаться с... с ЭТИМ, что бы вы не делали.

Comment: @oleksandrigo Нет, может я чего то недопонимаю, но... смотри. Допустим, у меня есть бот с инлайн кнопками. Я нажимаю на инлайн кнопку, и бот меня заводит в функцию, в которой я должен записать свое ФИО. Опять таки, если посылать сигнала с квери хендлера на месседж хендлер, ничего не выйдет, месседж их будет игнорить. Тут скорее по другому - как посылать с квери на месседж хендлер без костылей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штош. Вот вам небольшой пример кода, как должно работать то что вы хотите. (вроде)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class InputData(StatesGroup):
    input_fio = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("ввести фио", callback_data="fio_input"))
    await message.answer("привет вот клавиатура", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="fio_input")
async def fio_call(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.answer("Введите ваше ФИО")
    await InputData.input_fio.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=InputData.input_fio)
async def fio_input(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Ваше ФИО - {message.text}")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

Что если попробовать функцию внутри функции

```
async def checkname(query: CallbackQuery):
async def checkname_2(message: types.Message):
msg = message.text
return checkname_2
```